# How to stop reactivity of variable in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, reactive-programming

I am working on nuxt 3 and I need to stop the reactivity of the `reactive` constant. As I have one formData object and Once we click on submit I need to remove some keys from the formData object.

I have assigned formData in another variable like `submitData = formData` and used `delete submitData.key` but it removes the `key` from formData as well and I need that should not be removed from the main formData object

Comment: so, you want to deep copy an object? `like submitData = formData`  well of course that won't work if you know how objects work in javascript

Comment: You need to clone (deep copy) an object, that's the term.

Comment: this is a problem that can be memory intensive you should provide your code to get the best solution. of course if you are confident that a RAM overflow will never happen to your application you can use `toRaw` -> `const tmp = submitData[key]; delete submitData[key];` -> `setup form` -> `submitData[key] = tmp` this will cause no side effects and minimize memory loss. or something like `formData.delete(key)` might be more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, You can use the `toRaw` function to obtain the original non-reactive version of the `formData` object and then use the reactive function to create a reactive copy of the `formData` object and assign to `submitData` variable.

Demo **:**

```
import { reactive, toRaw } from 'vue';

const formData = {...}

const submitData = reactive({ ...toRaw(formData) });

delete submitData.key;
```

Comment: Rohìt Jíndal It's work... Thank you very much for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shallow copy of `formData`

```
const submitData = { ...formData };
```

Or deep copy using `cloneDeep` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

```
const submitData = _.cloneDeep(formData);
```

Both will create a new object with the same properties and values as the original object. However, the new object is a separate entity in memory, distinct from the original object. Modifications made to the copy won't affect the original formData object.

Comment: Tony, Thanks for your answer! I just used `const submitData = { ...formData };` but now when I changed any key like `delete submitData.key` it is also deleted from `formData` variable as well

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya This is not how it works, you won't be able to reproduce what you describe. I'd suggest to check on the subject first, this is fundamental to JS and not specific to Vue

Comment: but i can be able to assign `submitData = formData` without any error and formData is reactive using `const formData = reactive({... ... ...})`

Comment: If i use `const formData = {... ... ...}` instead `const formData = reactive({... ... ...})` then is I assign `submitData = formData` then formData will no effect I think so

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya, you should post your simplify code here. The reason when you used `const submitData = { ...formData };` and `delete submitData.key` but it still affects `formData` might be because your `formData` is nested object. This is the difference between shallow copy and deep copy. However, without seeing the actual code, we can only make assumptions.

Comment: There is a bunch of code but I just write my simple issue with variables and I think it's pretty clear once I got a solution I'll set this. Thank you very much for affording on this